# PostGIS function to find zip codes with radius in miles?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have very little knowledge and understanding Postgres/PostGIS. I am having trouble by using the **ST_PointInsideCircle** function for radius that uses miles or meters or degrees.
I think this function expects degrees in radius parameter. I have a table with all zip codes with lat/long and I have input with lat/long/radius (miles).
I need to select all the ZIP codes found inside that radius and provided lat/long.

Can anyone help me to find right function or script?

Postgres 9.5 /PostGIS installed.

```
lat=37.6210700000000031, 
long=-122.429737000000003,
radius=5 miles
```

my code :

```
SELECT zip_code from mytable 
  where ST_PointInsideCircle(ST_Point(mytable.latitude,mytable.longitude), 37.6210700000000031, -122.429737000000003, 5);
```

Comment: what does this have to do with zip codes?

Comment: The lat/long are from mytable. My table columns: zip_code,lat,long

Comment: That's cool, I don't think that's at all relevant to the question though. You could just as well say, find points within radius in miles?

Comment: Most people work this problem the opposite way. You download the ZCTAs from the census, and then you check to see what ZCTA has the point you're looking for with point-in-polygon search. It's far safer then your circle method.

Comment: I have to create a function (myfunction) in Postgres. Input parameters are lat float, long float and radius float. Function should return all zip codes from mytable within a given radius from lat/long of another zip code.Thank you agian

Comment: Regarding working with problem the opposite way. Could you please give me a specific example?  I looked into point-in-polygon using Postgres SQL and its not clear to me. Can you help me undestand how I can use radius in miles for this search?

Comment: Well to start off this explain this statement (in the question please) what does this mean "I have a table with all zip codes with lat / long" . You think Zip Codes are a point? So you're trying to draw a circle with a radius around that point, to find out if another point is within it, is that correct?

Comment: May I ask you where you got the full mapping of long/lat to zip?

Answer (score 3):

Always use `ST_DWithin` for proximity searches.

All functions executing planar operations calculate with the unit of the CRS of the input geometries. You will have to set the correct SRID for your coordinates and/or transform them if needed - here we do both, deprojecting your geometries to EPSG:4326 and casting to `GEOGRAPHY`, to calulate on a spherical model of Earth and accept *meter* as parameter:

```
SELEC
  zip_code 
FROM
  mytable
WHERE 
  ST_DWithin(
    ST_Transform(
      ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(mytable.lon, mytable.lat), <SRID>),
      4326
    )::GEOGRAPHY,
    ST_Transform(
      ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-122.429737000000003, 37.6210700000000031), <SRID>),
      4326
    )::GEOGRAPHY,
    <MILES> * 1609.344
  )
;
```

where `<SRID>` is the SRID of your data.

Note that this transformation and casting need respective index conditions in place in order to benefit from it.

Comment: -122 is not a valid latitude; you need to correct ordinate order, too.

Comment: @Vince ah sure, thanks, I thought I corrected the order...the values are only copypaste though. They are switched now.

Comment: @Yelena Lepina you are welcome! consider accepting the answer that solved your question.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you! I only had to adjust `RETURNS TABLE(zip_code VARCHAR)` line as my zip codes are defined as VARCHAR in table.

Comment: This function doesn't work for me unfortunately. With radius set to 30 miles It's pulling zip codes into result set that are 800+ miles away.

Comment: I think I made it work. The `lat` and `lon` need to be reversed in the function example. `ST_Point()` fn expects longitude as the first argument

Comment: @demisx good catch, thx. Seeing this 7 years later I feel like removing that function part entirely. Really doesn't make sense, this is very basic spatial SQL syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The functions are built to use the same units as parameters. As you said yourself the funtion does expect your 5 miles in degrees. You can either transform your miles in degrees. That is dependend on your position on the earth. Or you transform your points to a projected coordinate reference. Then you can use miles (as transformed to meters). The second way might be a bit easier.

Calculating distances depends on where you are to use the correct projection. Taking the coordinates of your example your point is in the UTM zone 10. Using this projection should give you the possibilty to transform your points into projected coordinates and use them for your calculation. The function you need is ST_Transform. In the example it uses the SRID 32610. It will first transfrom your point to UTM zone 10, then creates a point from your coordinates and takes the X and Y coordinate as input for the circle. At the end it translates 5 miles into 8050 meters as UTM is in meters.

```
ST_PointInsideCircle(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(lat,lon),4326),32610),ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-122.429737000000003 37.6210700000000031)',4326),32610)),ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-122.429737000000003 37.6210700000000031)',4326),32610)),8050)
```

Comment: no SRID in my table and no SRID  in API. Do I need to use a function to find SRID ( ST_SRID). Also, convert miles to meters, any function for that? Thank you for your help

Comment: SRID should be 4326 (WGS84) which is the common geographic coordinate reference that uses degree. Miles to meters... 5*1609